# What is the best method of detecting the next page break on an Excel workbook in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, worksheet, page-break

I am creating a macro that compiles variable lengths of data onto a worksheet. The amount of data on this worksheet can be as little as one row of data, up to hundreds of rows of data (column range is fixed for all rows (A:I)). After the last row of data, there needs to be a "footer". This "footer" cannot be placed within Excel's Footer section, but has to occupy the last 5 rows of the worksheet. When the user saves the sheet (regardless of it being in excel, pdf, or word format) the "footer" cannot be split between two pages. I have built a macro that calculates which row will be the start of the next page. For this worksheet, 10 rows equals one page. The 11th row will be the start of the next page. And so on (page 3 starts on row 21). This macro works because I ensure all the rows have a height of 40 (.RowHeight = 40). However, this macro approach will not work anymore because the data in certain cells may contain enough characters to wrap around, requiring the row to be longer than 40. What would be a better method for detecting the last row on a worksheet before a new pagebreak starts?

Here is my current code for detecting if the footer will fit onto the last worksheet page or if the footer needs to be applied to the next page (and avoiding being added in the middle of the pagebreak). Again, this code will not work now because I cannot rely on all the rows being a constant height value. A couple of other notes about the code below: FindLastRow is a function that finds the last range address on the provided parameters (worksheet name and column number). Using .Row returns just the address's row value. The first line of data on the COA worksheet starts on row 13. Rows 1:12 are dedicated to the documents header information. As specified by the users, if the Footer must be put on a separate page, then at least one line of data must be moved onto that new page as well (hopefully this better explains all the extra lines of code in the last IF/Else statement when adding the Footer to the next page). Thank you for your help and advice.

```
Public Sub COA_DetectedEOD()
'Purpose: Sub checks when the COA document ends and determines where
'the footer will go.
'If footer does not fit on the current last page of the document,
'then the last data point is cut/pasted at the start of the next new page
'and the footer is placed at the bottom of that new page.
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Lrow As Integer, i As Integer, cnt As Integer
Dim PgBtm As Integer, FtReq As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("COA")
Lrow = FindLastRow(ws, 1).Row   'Find the last row on COA sheet

FtReq = 4   'Number of rows required for footer to fit on page.
PgBtm = 22  'Row number of last row on COA page
i = 1       'COA page count
cnt = Lrow  'counter to calculate # of pages on COA.

'Determine how many pages are on the COA sheet
Do While cnt > 22
    cnt = cnt - 10  'each COA page is 10 rows
    i = i + 1       'count # of pages
Loop

'Update PgBtm variable with the last row number on page
PgBtm = (i * 10) + 12

'------------------------ ADD FOOTER ------------------------
If PgBtm - Lrow > FtReq Then
    Call COA_InsertFooter(Lrow + 2) 'The "+2" ensures the footer has a little separation from the data. 
Else
    'The page is too full for the footer to fit. Move last data row to the next new page
    ws.Rows(Lrow).EntireRow.Cut ws.Range("A" & PgBtm + 1)
    'Re-format row height on cut row (row Height goes back to default)
    ws.Range("A" & Lrow).RowHeight = 40
    'Add Footer to the bottom of the page
    Call COA_InsertFooter(PgBtm + 10 - FtReq)
End If

Terminate:
Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Edit: Below is my new solution for finding the page breaks on a worksheet. Each COA data row on the worksheet can have any row height value. This makes it challenging to predict where page breaks will be. I fill 45 rows (only column A) with the value "x". One whole page without any data on it equates 45 rows when row.height = 10. By doing this, the Range.HpageBreak property will give me the row value of each pages page break. Once I know where the last page break is I can determine if my Footer can fit onto the page, or if I have to move it onto the next page.

```
Public Sub COA_DetectPageBreak()
'Purpose: Sub detects where the last page break is on the COA worksheet.
'Depending where the page break is, the footer will be inserted on
'the last page of the COA or placed on a new (last) page.
'If the Footer must be put onto a new page, then the last row of data will
'need to be cut/pasted to the new last page. Footer should be put as far
'down on the page as possible without getting cut off.

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Lrow As Long        'Last row of COA data on worksheet
Dim pb As HPageBreak    'Page Break location = top left cell address.
Dim BtmPgRow As Long    'Last row before the page break
Dim LDataRowH As Long   'Row height of the last data row

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("COA")
Lrow = FindLastRow(ws, 1).Row    'User Defined Function

'Add 45 x's to each row after COA data, change the row's height to 10
ws.Range(ws.Cells(Lrow + 1, "A"), ws.Cells(Lrow + 46, "A")).Value = "x"
ws.Range(ws.Cells(Lrow + 1, "A"), ws.Cells(Lrow + 46, "A")).RowHeight = 10

With ws
    For Each pb In ws.HPageBreaks
        'Find the last page break on worksheet
        If pb.Location.Row >= Lrow Then
            'Assign the last pagebreak row to variable
            '"-1", b/c pb.location.row is the row number under the pagebreak
            BtmPgRow = pb.Location.Row - 1

            'Check if Footer fits between the last data row and before the pagebreak
            '14 rows at row.height = 10 is required for Footer to fit
            If BtmPgRow - Lrow >= 14 Then

                'Remove the x's
                ws.Range(ws.Cells(Lrow + 1, "A"), ws.Cells(Lrow + 46, "A")).Value = ""
                'Add Footer to the bottom of the page
                'The -14 spaces the Footer as far down on the page as possible
                'User defined Sub that pastes and formats my Footer onto the COA worksheet.
                Call COA_InsertTableFooter(BtmPgRow - 14)
            Else
                'The Footer will not fit on the page. Move it to the next page
                'The last line of COA data must be moved to the new page too
                'Save the last data row's height value
                LDataRowH = ws.Range("A" & Lrow).RowHeight
                
                'Cut data row, paste on first row on new page.
                .Rows(Lrow).EntireRow.Cut ws.Range("A" & BtmPgRow + 1)
                
                'Re-format row height on cut row (row height goes back to default)
                ws.Range("A" & Lrow).RowHeight = LDataRowH
                
                'Change Lrow to BtmPgRow + 1
                Lrow = BtmPgRow + 1
                'Find the new page bottom by looping to next pb
            End If
        End If
    Next pb
End With

Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: This will be much simpler if you export the table(s) to word.  Then in word you just check if each row in the 'footer' is on the same page and the same page as the last row and as the last row of the table. Alternatively, as you are using word, just put your footer table into the footer of the document.  It will be fairly straightforward to do all the code from within excel.

Comment: Hi @freeflow, I am unfamiliar with VBA code that manipulates a Word document. Could you provide me with a bit of the coding structure to your idea? If solving my coding issue is easier by moving the table to Word, then I would like to explore that idea. In my original post, I mentioned that I have a macro that exports the table to word. However, I'm still troubleshooting that subroutine (the exported table does not properly fit on a regularly formatted word doc). Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi Qstein.  Its not that hard.  You now have an opportunity for new learning.  The last row of your table and all paragraphs to the end of the footer table should be set to the paragraph property 'Keep With Next'. NO need to put your footer in the actual footer IYSWIM.

Comment: You are right @freeflow. I will most likely still implement your solution when I troubleshoot my Word export functionality. It is a good learning opportunity for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a draft code:

```
Sub SubInsertFooter()
    
    Dim RngPrint As Range
    Dim RngFooter As Range
    Dim RngRow As Range
    Dim DblFooterRowsHeight As Double
    Dim DblFooterSingleRowHeight As Double
    Dim DblMaxHeight As Double
    Dim DblHeightSum As Double
    Dim DblRow As Double
    Dim DblCounter As Double
    Dim DblUsedRangeRowsHeight() As Double
    
    ActiveSheet.ClearContents
    
    Set RngPrint = Range("A11:G60")
    Set RngFooter = Range("A1:G5")
    
    DblFooterSingleRowHeight = 40
    DblFooterRowsHeight = DblFooterSingleRowHeight * 5
    DblMaxHeight = DblFooterSingleRowHeight * 10
    
    RngPrint.FormulaR1C1 = "=ROW(RC)+1-" & RngPrint.Row
    RngPrint.Value2 = RngPrint.Value2
    
    RngFooter.Value2 = "FOOTER"
    RngFooter.Columns(1).Value2 = DblFooterSingleRowHeight
    
    For Each RngRow In RngPrint.Rows
        
        Randomize
        RngRow.RowHeight = (Rnd() * 2 + 1) * 20
        RngRow.Cells(1, 1).Value2 = RngRow.EntireRow.RowHeight
        
    Next
    
    MsgBox "Here i stop the code so you can check the initial data. You can resume the code once you've had your look.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly
    Stop
    
    ReDim DblUsedRangeRowsHeight(1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 0 To 1) As Double
    
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        For DblRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
            DblUsedRangeRowsHeight(DblRow, 0) = .Rows(DblRow).RowHeight
        Next
    End With
    
    For Each RngRow In RngPrint.Rows
        
        Select Case DblHeightSum + RngRow.RowHeight + DblFooterRowsHeight
            Case Is < DblMaxHeight
                DblHeightSum = DblHeightSum + RngRow.RowHeight
            Case Is = DblMaxHeight
                DblUsedRangeRowsHeight(RngRow.Row + 1, 1) = 1
                DblHeightSum = 0
            Case Is > DblMaxHeight
                DblUsedRangeRowsHeight(RngRow.Row, 1) = 1
                DblHeightSum = RngRow.RowHeight
        End Select
        If Range(RngRow, RngPrint.Rows(RngPrint.Rows.Count)).Height + RngFooter.Height <= DblMaxHeight And DblHeightSum <= RngRow.RowHeight Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    
    
    With RngPrint
        
        DblCounter = 0
        
        For DblRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row + 1 To .Row Step -1
            Select Case True
                Case Is = DblCounter > 0
                    
                    For DblCounter = DblCounter To RngFooter.Rows.Count Step -1
                        
                        Set RngRow = Rows(DblRow).Offset(DblCounter)
                        RngRow.EntireRow.RowHeight = DblUsedRangeRowsHeight(DblRow + DblCounter - RngFooter.Rows.Count, 0)
                    Next
                    DblCounter = 0
                    
                Case Is = DblRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row + 1, DblUsedRangeRowsHeight(DblRow, 1) = 1
                    RngFooter.Copy
                    Set RngRow = Rows(DblRow)
                    RngRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    RngRow.Resize(RngFooter.Rows.Count).Rows.RowHeight = DblFooterSingleRowHeight
                    If DblRow <> .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row + 1 Then
                        DblCounter = DblCounter * -1 + RngFooter.Rows.Count
                        DblRow = DblRow + 1
                    End If
                Case Else
                    DblCounter = DblCounter - 1
            End Select
        Next
    End With
    
    
    
End Sub
```

Place it in a module, select a new sheet and run it. It will paste a fake footer in range A1:G5 and a fake list in range A11:G60 with random row heights. It will then add the footer to the list accordingly.

Is this the kind of algorithm you are looking for?

Comment: Hi @Evil Blue Monkey, Thank you for sending me your code. I was hoping for a simpler solution to my Footer problem. I've been testing code that uses the Range.PageBreak property to determine if the Footer will fit onto the page or not. However, the PageBreak property requires cell data before and after the page break to return True. The code pastes 5 rows of "x" into column A after the actual data ends. Then I loop over those 5 rows, looking for the Range.PageBreak property = True. It is not an elegant solution...

Comment: Maybe it's the late hour, but i can't understand your comment. You said you have a list of data with rows of different height that has to accomodate on each printed sheet a footer of 5 row 40 point high each. Isn't my draft code providing you a way to edit the said list so that each page will be printed as requested? You asked specifically to have the footers added as actual rows in the list. I don't see other way than adding the footers as actual rows in the list. What did i miss?